# Count Distinct USER_ID and distinct USER_ID and TYPE combination for each PRODUCT - SQL

Tags: sql

I need help with an SQL query,

I have a DB with 3 columns - **USER_ID**, **TYPE** and **PRODUCT**.

I want to show for each **PRODUCT** the number of **distinct USER_IDs**, and also the number of **distinct USER_IDs for each TYPE**.

Please be aware that the DB can contain rows with the same values (for some of the columns and sometimes all of the rows).

Example,

| USER_ID | TYPE | PRODUCT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11111 | Adidas | Shirt |
| 11111 | Adidas | Shirt |
| 11111 | Nike | Shirt |
| 22222 | Nike | Shirt |
| 11111 | Adidas | Short |
| 22222 | Nike | Short |
| 22222 | Puma | Short |

**I should get the following output:**

*for the **Shirt** product:*

- *distinct USER_IDs* - 2
- *distinct USER_IDs according to type:*

1. *Adidas* - 1
2. *Nike* - 2

*for the **Short** product:*

- *distinct USER_IDs* - 2
- *distinct USER_IDs according to type:*

1. *Adidas* - 1
2. *Nike* - 1
3. *Puma* - 1

result as possible tables:

| PRODUCT | TYPE | COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Shirt | - | 2 |
| Shirt | Adidas | 1 |
| Shirt | Nike | 2 |
| Short | - | 2 |
| Short | Adidas | 1 |
| Short | Nike | 1 |
| Short | PUMA | 1 |

I want to avoid JOIN / UNION operations.
I can use window functions.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please include the results you desire for your example data

Comment: hey @MatBailie :) I added the data that I need to be able to get. I'm not worried about the specific schema, I just neet to be able to retrieve this needed data

Comment: Please format the results ***as a table***, the structure you want the sql query to return. *(I think you just want ROLLUP, but it's not clear.)*

Comment: Feel free to upvote and/or accept answers to ***any*** of your questions.

Comment: @MatBailie can I solve it using a window function? maybe partition by? what will be the best performance-wise?

Comment: No, this isn't what window / analytic functions are for.

Comment: Spark SQL and mysql are two different database products with different implementations of sql. Removed conflicting product tags. Please add the one back that you actually use.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using (MySQL, Postgres, Oracle, SQL Server, something else)? Please add the tag of your database to your question. See [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) to know why tagging is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear precisely what you want, but I think it's just ROLLUP.

```
SELECT
  product,
  type,
  COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)
FROM
  your_table
GROUP BY
  product,
  type
WITH
  ROLLUP
ORDER BY
  product,
  type
```

Comment: so actually i can do the rollout only on the type right?

Comment: @sweet add `HAVING GROUPING(product) = 0` after the `WITH ROLLUP` to keep only the rows where the product isn't rolled up.

Comment: `WITH ROLLUP` is deprecated, you should use `GROUP BY ROLLUP (product, type)` or better to fit with OP `GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ( (product, type), (product) )` and then you don't need that `HAVING`

Comment: @charlieface The question used to be tagged MySQL